# Java XWPF, set paragraph hanging indentation

Tags: java, javafx, ms-word, xwpf

I am coding a program in JavaFX to convert essays with no indentation and such as MLA styled documents. My question right now, how do I enable **hanging indentation** to a specific xwpfParagraph? I am using Apache poi 3.17.

I already wrote to word document, and everything seems to be working fine. I'm just not sure how to set the hanging indentation.

I'm aware of the function `setIndentationHanging()`, but I am not sure how to get it to work. I tried using `xwpfParagraph.setIndentationHanging(X);` but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
String tempMessage = textArea.getText();
XWPFParagraph p1 = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run = p1.createRun();
p1.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
p1.setSpacingBetween(2.0);
run.setText(tempMessage + "\n");
run.setFamilyFont("Times New Roman");
tempMessage = "";
```

This code snippet is the one I am using to create the word document, create a paragraph, assign the paragraph some text (tempMessage), set alignments and spacing. I would like to know how I could go around adding **Hanging Indentation** for this specific paragraph.

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't seem to work? Please look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and I am sure people would be happy to help.

Comment: Is it more clear now? I am specifically looking for a code snippet/explanation to enable hanging indentation for a specific paragraph in an xwpfDocument.

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of Styles in Word? If you're trying to reformat documents to meet a certain standard it would be better to define a set of styles to meet the standard and apply them, rather than formatting things directly.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `xwpParagraph.setIndentationHanging();` was working as intended, but the value of the parameter is not as I thought.  `xwpfParagraph.setIndentationHanging(720);` only indents the paragraph by **half an inch!** I had been using values such as 10, 5, etc.

Comment: Word uses POINTS for most measurements - that's cleary stated in both the end-user and object model documentation.

Comment: @CindyMeister so does agile scrum, but that doesn't mean they actually mean anything.

Comment: Actually, the unit OP is referring to in this context is _twips_; and they do mean something.